# Spark Error in Dataproc - Insufficient memory for java runtime environment

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have tried to execute `spark-shell` command in Dataproc after working with Hive and I am getting error regarding insufficient memory;

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f79e8443000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
here is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
An error report file with more information is saved as:
/home/nadarsneha44/hs_err_pid32312.log
```

So, I have a couple questions:

1. What can be the cause of the memory error?
2. How can I increase memory size to overcome the error?

Comment: Show us the complete stacktrace.

Comment: You need to provide more details about the problem, your configurations, memory specs etc. to solve the issue.

Comment: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f79e8443000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/nadarsneha44/hs_err_pid32312.log

Answer (score 0):

The first checkpoint is to verify if the cluster nodes are effectively out of memory. If all the memory in the nodes is being used, the solution is increasing the resources in the nodes by

- Creating a new cluster and changing the machine type or
- [Adding extra nodes](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/scaling-clusters#using_scaling) of the same machine type to the existing cluster.

If you find out that the memory in the nodes is not totally used (this is, there is memory available), then you need to [tune the `spark-shell`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties), for example, setting a custom value for `spark.executor.memory` or other memory properties.

Monitoring the memory in the nodes is important because if the error persists, it is possible that the memory error comes from the host/driver machine (the machine where you execute the `spark-shell`) and not from the cluster. You can verify this by monitoring the memory usage in the driver machine when the error occurs.